# mysql: linking 2 tables with 2 different fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `user` table, e.g.

```
userId
userName
```

and I have a `message` table, e.g.

```
messageId
messageToId
messageFromId
messageContent
```

I am trying to make a query to pull a message, but also get the user names from the user table based on the `messageToId` and `messageFromId`.

I have done this before with only 1 field between tables, e.g.

```
SELECT message.*, user.userName
  FROM message, user
 WHERE user.userId = message.messageToId
   AND messageId = (whatever)
```

But I am having trouble with 2 links.

I want the result as follows:

```
messageId
messageToId
toUserName
messageFromId
fromUserName
messageContent
```

Any help would be much appreciated, or if someone had another way of attempting a private message system with PHP/MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to use [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and different table aliases:

```
SELECT m.*, u1.userName AS toUserName, u2.username AS fromUserName
FROM message m INNER JOIN user u1 ON m.messageToId = u1.userId
    INNER JOIN user u2 ON m.messageFromId = u2.userId
WHERE messageId = "XXX";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a join from to achieve this:

```
SELECT `m`.*, 
       `to`.`userName` AS `to`,
       `from`.`userName` AS `from`,
FROM `message` `m`
JOIN `user` `to` ON `m`.`messageToId` = `to`.`userId`
JOIN `user` `from` ON `m`.`messageFromId` = `from`.`userId`
WHERE `m`.`messageId` = 1
```

So you join against the user table twice to get both users for a particular message. To do this you need to use table aliases as I have done with `to` and `from` so that you distinguish between them.

I have also used a field alias to get their usernames separately eg:

```
`to`.`username` AS `from`
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
SELECT b.userName AS author, c.userName AS reciever, a.messageId, a.messageContent FROM message a JOIN user b ON a.messageFromId = b.userId JOIN user c ON a.messageToId = c.userId
```